# Disabling divs after they've been clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a Tic Tac Toe game and I'd like to stop the player being able to "overwrite" cells that have already been taken. [Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/f1apoya1/5/) the game.

I tried using this:

```
function stopClick() {
    if (document.getElementsByClassName("pos").innerHTML !== "") {
        $(this).disabled = "disabled";
    }
}
```

And a multitude of other similar functions but nothing works. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: You have jquery but used `getElementsByClassName()`? Also `$(this).disabled` isn't right. `this.disabled` or `$(this).attr("disabled", true)`

Comment: Ah yes, I need to stop jumbling them up.

Comment: Could you add logs to different parts of the flow? As in, one at the top of the function to make sure it's being called, one within the `if` statement to make sure it's getting in there. This will help you narrow down what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your game and a working version can be found here: 
https://jsfiddle.net/f1apoya1/7/

Basically add a class:

```
.already-played {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

and to your `updateButtons` function:

```
function updateButtons() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            $("#c" + i + "" + j).text(board[i][j] == false ? "x" : board[i][j] == true ? "o" : "");
            if (board[i][j]) {
                $("#c" + i + "" + j).addClass('already-played');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, I added `$(this).addClass('already-played');` to the myMove part to disabled where x's have been placed too.

Comment: That's awesome. (:

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$(this ).css( 'pointer-events', 'none' );
```

Answer (score 0):

1) if you want to use js, you can add some class to block that user checked. And check for this class in you click listener

2) if you want to use css. There is pointer-events: none
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/